# magento with multiple jquerys

Tags: jquery, magento

There is already a version of jquery 1.8.3 in the current theme in my magento store, which is based on magento 1.8.1.
Now, I have to add some code, which depends on jquery 1.10.2. If I add the jquery 1.10.2 in the page.xml, there is something wrong for the theme. But if I remove jquery 1.10.2, my new code could not work.
how to solve this conflict.

Comment: You upgrade you system to use jQuery 1.10, or you don't use code that depends on jQuery 1.10.2.

Comment: Alan Storm answered your question, you're very fortunate lol. Check out his blog

Answer (score 0):

The migrate plugin may help: http://blog.jquery.com/2013/01/31/jquery-migrate-1-1-0-released/

Note, however, that adding a second library to Magento is a bad idea - it is already script-heavy.  If you can, use Script.aculo.us scripts instead - which is the javascript library used by core Magento.